Isar limit amount of objects in the collection
Currently I'm trying to find informations about a possibility to limit the amount of items in the collection.
This is important for my usecase because I want to have 2 collections (possible 2 instances) one with 'quick access' for around 1000 to 2000 items and other one containing all the data (even 100000 and more items). Which is going to be paginated and include the records that are older than the 1000-2000 stored in the 'quick access'.
After this brief background, I was wondering if there is a way of making it easier than checking if number of items is greater than eg. 1000, then taking the oldest record saving it to the other collection and after that saving item to quick access collection
Looking for your ideas!
